# Help with SFDX 2GP release version error: "You cannot install an unlocked package without a namespace into an org with a namespace."

Tags: salesforcedx, 2gp, sfdx-error, cumulusci

I am trying to release an Unlocked 2GP package that has an Unlocked package dependency (UnofficialSF component), and when SF servers verify the dependencies I get the same error every time:

```
Error: You cannot install an unlocked package without a namespace into an org with a namespace.
```

It is my understanding that 2GP does NOT use any sort of packaging org (which would have been namespaced) to build the package, so I'm not sure what namespaced org this is flagging an error for.  I have scoured SFDX's documentation as well as user forums and can't find anyone dealing with this same error.

I have tried releasing a package version using both CLI and CumulusCI, and I get the same error in both scenarios.

When listing packages in my Dev Hub:

```
Namespace Prefix  Name                                              Id                  Alias  Description  Type
ref02             Refugees-Support-Unlocked                         0Ho1U000000TNSaSAO                      Unlocked
```

For those familiar with CumulusCI the beginning of my CCI.yml file looks like:

```
project:
    name: Refugees-Support
    package:
        name: 'Refugees-Support-Unlocked'
        namespace: 'ref02'
        api_version: '50.0'
    dependencies:
        - github: 'https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/PMM'
        - github: 'https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Relationships'
        - version_id: 04t4W00000309DuQAI
        - version_id: 04t5G0000047xO4QAI
        - version_id: 04t5G000003rUaWQAU
```

My prior sfdx-project file looked like this, for when running the release via SFDX CLI:

```
    "namespace": "ref02",
    "sourceApiVersion": "52.0",
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "Refugees Support (Unlocked)",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "definitionFile" : "orgs/release.json"
        }
    ],
    "dependencies": [
        {
            "package" : "Relationships@3.12.0.LATEST"           
        },
        {
            "package": "PMM@1.29.0.LATEST"
        },
        {
            "package": "FlowActionsBasePack@2.36.0.LATEST"
        },
        {
            "package": "FlowScreenComponentsBasePack@2.7.5.LATEST"
        },
        {
            "package": "Datatable@3.3.2.LATEST"
        }
     ],
    "postInstallUrl": "https://github.com/Cath-Strategic-Tech/Refugees-Support/releases",
    "packageAliases": {
        "PMM": "04t6g000008C2xMAAS",
        "Relationships": "04t2E000003sm94QAA",
        "FlowActionsBasePack": "04t4W0000034KcuQAE",
        "FlowScreenComponentsBasePack": "04t5G0000047xO4QAI",
        "Datatable": "04t5G000003rUaWQAU",
        "Refugees Support (Unlocked)": "0Ho1U000000TNSQSA4"
    }
}
```

My sfdx-project when attempting the run via CumulusCI looks pretty simple:

`{"packageDirectories": [{"path": "force-app", "default": true}], "namespace": null, "sourceApiVersion": "52.0"}`

Comment: Are you creating the unlocked package with the namespace?

Comment: Initially I was, but then I attempted without namespace as well, received the same error.

Comment: Is your DevHub linked with a namespace?

Comment: Our DevHub has multiple namespaces linked to it, following the new process for releasing 2GP packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the Namespace collision rule criteria discussed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_namespace_collisions.htm).

I am assuming that you are building a **namespaced Unlocked package** that has the dependencies on the **non-Namespaced Unlocked package**.

During unlocked package creation, the org is getting generated with a namespace in the backend and all the dependent unlocked packages are failing to install due to the conflict resolution rule [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_namespace_collisions.htm).

Some possible solutions to this issue is as below

1. Create an unlocked package without a namespace

OR

2. If dependent unlocked packages are open source, create your own package and package version with a namespace or alternatively incorporate the code in your package.

Also, I suggest, raising an idea on IdeaExchange to product teams to allow support your use case in the product.

Comment: +1 - another option is to vendor the 3rd-party unlocked package contents into your package, if open source.

Comment: @DavidReed Good point! Let me bake that in as well as another option.

Answer (score 0):

If You are trying to install the unlocked package using sfdx-cli then you must create a scratch org without a namespace. Use flag "-n" while creating scratch org using sfdx-cli.

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -v DEVHUB_USER -a Org_alias -d 1 -n
```